# Apache HTTPS configuration issue. Have to specify port 80 to get "https://" but need to access without specifying any port.

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, httpd.conf

I followed [this](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Https) guide step by step to set up SSL connection for my web portal. Earlier I was able to access it using http:// but now I have to specify port 80 i.e. I have to use https://:80 to access the portal. If I access https:// it shows me the default Apache test page, which says -

> Testing 123..This page is used to test the proper operation of the Apache HTTP server after it has been installed. If you can read this page it means that this site is working properly. This server is powered by CentOS.

I need to access the portal using https:// without port. Any help is appreciated.

**httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/portals/portals/wsgi.py
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/portals/portals
   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mysite.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/mysite.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mysite.crt
   <Location "/mysite/authenticate">
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "wsgi protected"
       Require valid-user
       AuthBasicProvider wsgi
       WSGIAuthGroupScript /var/www/html/portals/portals/wsgi.py
       WSGIAuthUserScript /var/www/html/portals/portals/wsgi.py
   </Location>



   <Directory /var/www/html/portals/portals>
      <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
      </Files>
   </Directory>

   Alias /media/ /var/www/html/portals/media/
   Alias /static/ /var/www/html/portals/static/

   <Directory /var/www/html/portals/static>
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/html/portals/media>
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/portals/portals/wsgi.py
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/portals/portals
   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mysite.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/mysite.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mysite.crt
   <Location "/mysite/authenticate">
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "wsgi protected"
       Require valid-user
       AuthBasicProvider wsgi
       WSGIAuthGroupScript /var/www/html/portals/portals/wsgi.py
       WSGIAuthUserScript /var/www/html/portals/portals/wsgi.py
   </Location>



   <Directory /var/www/html/portals/portals>
      <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
      </Files>
   </Directory>

   Alias /media/ /var/www/html/portals/media/
   Alias /static/ /var/www/html/portals/static/

   <Directory /var/www/html/portals/static>
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/html/portals/media>
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have followed the instructions correctly.  The instructions say that the `<VirtualHost *:80>` element should be something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/httpdocs>
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/httpdocs
    ServerName yoursite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and there should be a "mirror" configuration port 443.

But you seem to have added in the stuff to enable the SSL engine, etcetera to the `<VirtualHost *:80>` element ... which is going to make Apache configure port 80 to expect / require "https:" connections.

Review your configurations and compare them with what the instructions actually tell you to do.

Can I also recommend reading the Apache documentation for the directives that you are using in your configs.   That way you can start to understand what the configs are actually saying.  That will give you a better chance of diagnosing problems if the "potted" instructions are not followed correctly.